# Process loop synchronously in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an $http request that is returning a bunch of rows. I need to process each of those results synchronously. Having trouble wrapping my brain around Angular.

Each of the records needs to be processed against a local SQLite database on an iOS device, and that is an asynchronous call.

If any of the loop records fail, I need to abort the entire operation (and loop).

Here's the code to see if it helps...

```
var username = $rootScope.currentUser;
            window.logger.logIt("Executing incremental sync with username " + username);

            var url = $rootScope.serviceBaseUrl + 'SyncData/GetSyncItems?userid=' + username + '&lastSyncDate=' + lastSyncDate.toString();
            var encoded = encoder.encode($CONFIG.serviceAccount);

            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;

            $http({ method: 'Get', url: url })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    var processes = [];

                    for (var i in data) {
                        var params = data[i].Params;
                        var paramsMassaged = params.replaceAll("[", "").replaceAll("]", "").replaceAll(", ", ",").replaceAll("'", "");
                        var paramsArray = paramsMassaged.split(",");
                        var process;

                        if (data[i].TableName === "Tabl1") {
                            window.logger.logIt("setting the process for a Table1 sync item");
                            process = $Table1_DBContext.ExecuteSyncItem(data[i].Query, paramsArray);
                        } else if (data[i].TableName === "Table2") {
                            window.logger.logIt("setting the process for an Table2 sync item");
                            process = $Table2_DBContext.ExecuteSyncItem(data[i].Query, paramsArray);
                        } else {
                            window.logger.logIt("This table is not included in the sync process. You have an outdated version of the application. Table: " + data[i].TableName);
                        }

                        window.logger.logIt("got to here...");

                        processes.push(process);
                    }

                    window.logger.logIt("Finished syncing all " + data.length + " records in the list...");

                    $q.all(processes)
                        .then(function (result) {
                            // Update the LastSyncDate here
                            $DBConfigurations_DBContext.UpdateLastSyncDate(data[i].CreatedDate);

                            alert("finished syncing all records");
                        }, function (result) {
                            alert("an error occurred.");
                        });
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("An error occurred retrieving the items that need to be synced.");
                });
```

Table2 ExecuteSyncItem function:

```
ExecuteSyncItem: function (script, params) {
    //window.logger.logIt("In the Table2 ExecuteSyncItem function...");

    //$DBService.ExecuteQuery(script, params, null);

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var data = $DBService.ExecuteQuery(script, params, null);

    if (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    } else {
        deferred.reject(data);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

DB Service code:

```
ExecuteQuery: function (query, params, success) {
    $rootScope.db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, params, success, onError);
    });
},
```

Update: In response to Maxim's question "did you log process method". Here's what I'm doing...

```
ExecuteSyncItem: function (script, params) {
    window.logger.logIt("In the Experiment ExecuteSyncItem function...");

    //$DBService.ExecuteQuery(script, params, null);

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var data = $DBService.ExecuteQuery(script, params, function () { window.logger.logIt("successCallback"); });

    if (data) {
        window.logger.logIt("success");
        deferred.resolve(data);
    } else {
        window.logger.logIt("fail");
        deferred.reject(data);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

"data" is undefined everytime. "fail" is logged everytime, as well as "successCallback". Also, the executeQuery IS working, and updating the data the way I expect.

So now, it's just a matter of the promise syntax I guess. If the ExecuteQuery isn't actually populating the "data" variable since it's asynchronous, how do I set the deferred.resolve() and deferred.reject stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on right way

I would use `$q.all`

### $q.all([async1(), async2() .....])

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when **all** of the input promises are resolved.
>
> Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash. **If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value**.

For example:

```
var processes = [];

processes.push(Process1);
processes.push(Process2);
/* ... */

 $q.all(processes)
            .then(function(result)
            {    
              /* here all above mentioned async calls finished */
 
              $scope.response_1 = result[0];
              $scope.response_2 = result[1]; 
             
            }, function (result) {
              alert("Error: No data returned");
            });
```

From your example  you run in loop  and call async methods (`Process1`, `Process2`) 10 times (8 and 2 respectively). In order to use `$q.all` the `Process1`, `Process2` must return promise.

So I would write it something like that:

```
var Process1 = function(stuff) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var data = $DBService.ExecuteQuery(stuff.query); // This is asynchronous
 
    if (data ) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
       } else {
    deferred.reject(data);
      }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: I was just updating my question when I saw your answer. Question: let's say of my 10 records returned, 8 of them are for process1, and 2 for process 2, your implementation looks like it processes both 1 and 2 for every record, did I read that right?

Comment: When you populated `Process1` and `Process2` with `Stuff` a.e. finished to load all 10 records, we are running `$q.all([Process1, Process2])`. When one of them fail, error callback will be called (see example I posted)

Comment: Ok, so doing the processes.push() queues up the different functions that need to be called for each of the ten records. Then it processes them in order. If any fails, it aborts the rest, is that correct?

Comment: I see your edit, use that in addition to your original answer?

Comment: Hmm, it's stopping on the var process = Process1(param1, param2);

Comment: Should "response" actually be "data" in your 2nd snippet?

Comment: Ok, another question. I've fixed everything and I'm getting the response: alert("Error: No data returned"); which means the $q.all failed. BUT, in each of my DBService.ExecuteQuery async calls, I added in the successCallback a logger message to see if it's actually getting a successful response, and it is. I'm getting 10 messages back for all 10 records saying it was successful. Since this is an asynchronous call, would data EVER be populated?

Comment: did you log `Process` method? be sure that in all cases you enters to `deferred.resolve(data);`